# Swagger No API definition provided

Tags: swagger, blazor, swagger-ui, blazor-webassembly, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I was implementing Swagger into my Blazor WebAssembly project and swagger does not seem to recognise any of my APIs? Can't seem to figure out the issue and was wondering if anyone knew why this might be occurring. Thanks in advance.

**Installed Swashbuckle.AspNetCore in the Server project**

My controllers do not use  the traditional `Route(["api/controller"])` but instead uses `Route(["controller"])` which I do not think would cause this issue.

Furthermore all  controller functions have been labelled with get/post/put e.g. `HttpGet[(...)] ...` etc

### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
            });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

       services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize);

        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use th   is method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are a bit fragmented by the various options and versions. But the relevant line is:

> - Add endpoints if you're using endpoint-based routing.

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapSwagger();     // add this line
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I seem to be getting `iendpointroutebuilder does not contain definition for mapswagger` when using `endpoints.MapSwagger()`

Comment: Hmm, what are your Blazor and Swashbuckle versions exactly?  It ought to work.

Comment: I'm using version 5.0 for Swashbuckle, this is the selected option when installing from NuGet. Not sure how I could check blazor version

Comment: The latest stable is 6.2.3 .  Version 5 seems ancient.  Just upgrade.

Comment: Would you know which version I might need to upgrade to? I think after a certain point the packages become incompatible with my project

Comment: Updated to 6.0 and made the change. All worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: SwashBuckle is built on .net standard 2.0 so you should be able to use the very latest version. Won't matter a whole lot but why forego some bugfixes etc?

Answer (score 0):

Check Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package version

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you omit a `[Route]` attribute on any of your API methods. Using version `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.2.3)`